# Can a change of all URLs to lower case with canonical from others cause traffic loss?

Tags: seo, google, url, case-sensitive

I've recently changed URLs to lower case. I'm also suffering from about 15% traffic drop from search engines, which started about a week after my change. Can this be related?

This is what I've done. Till now I've had all pages URLs look like this `http://mydomain.com/folder/Page`. And all internal links in the site were also to `http://mydomain.com/folder/Page2`.

All these have now turned into: `http://mydomain.com/folder/page` and `http://mydomain.com/folder/page2`.

And the page that still exists at `http://mydomain.com/folder/Page` has been add this in HTML `<head>`:

```
        <link rel="canonical" href="/folder/page" />
```

Have I done anything wrong? Would you recommend me to put it back to the way it was?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be related because one URL in lower case and upper case is not the same for search engines (thus Google). That's why you may lose some rankings on SERPs after changing the URLs. If it's the case, it can generate a loss of traffic.

In your case, putting the `rel="canonical"` tag is the best practice to avoid duplicate content issues. All what you've done is right!

Just wait a little bit to get your rankings back on SERPs.

Comment: Can you try giving a number estimation to `a little bit`?

Comment: Also - Would you recommend undoing the change?

Comment: An estimation is impossible, it depends on many factors. Otherwise, keep the lower case version, it's cleaner for URLs.